# Populate table in Word Template with VBA?

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

I'm filling in a Word template with data that's been collected from user input. In particular a (variable) number of documents is chosen, and information about each document fills a row of a table.

I've bookmarked several items in the template and successfully filled information in the header from my macro, but the table I'm not so sure with. I bookmarked the first cell and tried tabbing (with Chr(9)) through, and also tried passing an array. (In the template the table has only a first row. Usually tabbing past the last column creates an additional row.)

I can retieve cell contents with

```
   Word.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text
```

but can't write to the any cell except the first, where I placed a bookmark.

Can anyone offer a possible solution to populate the table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To populate table, use this code

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Blah Blah"
```

This will write to the first cell in the first table. Use a loop to fill the rest of the cells.

I would also recommend see this link.

**Topic: Automating Word Tables for Data Insertion and Extraction**

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx#Y1254

**Extract**:

> Summary: Learn how to automate the creation and formatting of tables in Word. Get information about optimizing performance, populating a table with data, formatting table structure, linking table data, and extracting data from a table. (25 printed pages)

Comment: Thanks Siddhath,

I was just adding more info to my post regarding this. That method allows me to retrieve data from the table, but not to insert. This is maybe because the document is protected from editing, although the cells I'm trying to edit allow this to be done manually. 

I'll read that link you posted and see if they offer any help.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually ran into a similar problem using Access to automate filling out a Word table template.  I found that if I opened the template in Word prior to running the VBA script, then the Word document is successfully filled out with the table information.  My code looks similar to yours as far as adding to it by row.  Because the number of fields to be transferred to the form is dynamic it didn't seem like bookmarks for each section would work.  If you have any update, I'd be happy to hear of a different way to resolve this.